# How to run javascript on a mobile website with console?

Tags: javascript, android

I wrote a JavaScript program that automates a process on a someone else's website, I run it on Chrome console and it works fine. I would like to do the same on my phone, but chrome mobile doesn't have console, any ideas?

So, I am NOT looking to debug or test the site or the script on a mobile environment, I actually need to run the script on a mobile phone rather than a PC.

I need to get the document object of the loaded page to get elements by ids and classes, and call click on them.

Is there a way of doing this?

**ANSWER!!**

As mentioned in the answer of the bookmark question above, I could run my JavaScript code on a mobile phone browser doing the same thing.
The only issue I have is that the browser removes the JavaScript: part of the code at the begining, and I have to scroll all the way to the front to type it
Thanks all

Comment: Haven't opened your original question yet, but you should have edited your original question to explain the difference between this and the duplicate rather than post another question. It was closed as a duplicate the first time probably because it looks the same. If it's different, it's your job to make that clear.

Comment: If your previous question was closed as duplicate, posting the exact same thing will get the same result.

Comment: Something that might work without pc is typing javascript:code in url

Comment: I did edit the first one, but it frustrating that all thosr users reported it without understanding it, the referred question wad totally fdifferent

Comment: the question mentioned now had an aaccepted answer that is not suitable for me, so it is not a valid duplicate

Comment: Right. You know you don't need a console to be able to run javascript?

Comment: I need to read the document object in the loaded page to automate the process

Comment: Then you needed to comment on the original question to say it is not duplicate and then edit the question to differentiate it so that it can go back into the reopen queue for review. In other words, you say why that answer didn't help and clarify your question. Adding multiple of the same question until you get your desired response is generally not the best way to go.

Comment: Will this work in mobile and on the loaded page?

Comment: this seems to be for a desktop

Comment: You can´t save it in mobile but you can run it

Comment: This actually worked, but for a complex script like mine, with multiple recurring functions might be hard to do. Will try it.

Comment: Hi Julian, it worked, but the issue is that the browser removes the JavaScript: part of the code at the begining, and I have to scroll all the way to the front to type it , any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You need to connect your device to your computer and access the console VIA the desktop chrome console. 
In the three little dot menu in the upper right corner, under `more tools`, there is and `Remote devices` options, click on it.
[image]

You can then select the device under `Devices` and the open pages on your mobile chrome will appear, Simply click on the inspect button.
( Sorry I don't have an image for that )

P.S. Make sur your device is in Developper mode, the USB device is activated and that the connection type with your computer is set to transfer file. You should also check to make sure you have to phone driver installed on your computer but usually it's there.

Comment: I did say in my question without connecting to pc

Comment: @masoodelsad well you can't.

Comment: @masoodelsad what you could do is import your script into an HTML pages with a `<script>` tag and access this page with your phone.

Comment: This is actually a good idea